# concatenar dos marker en Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, leaflet

Buenas soy nuevo en esto y tengo un proyecto en el que estoy trabajando con leaflet y utilizo con var marker, tengo ya hecha una parte de los marcadores pero el problema es que tengo ya demasiados y vi la posibilidad si se pueden concatenar para que aparezcan juntos algunos adjunto código y screen para un mayor entendimiento:

```
    echo "//----------  comparables cbba ultimos 10 registros  sucre --------------------------------------------
var suc10 = new L.markerClusterGroup({disableClusteringAtZoom: 17});
";
while ($suc10 = pg_fetch_row($c_suc10)) {
    if($suc10[6]==0 and $suc10[7]>=1){$cm3='m3';}
            else {if($suc10[6]==0 and $suc10[7]==0){$cm3='pin';}else{
                $cm3='mc3';
            }

    }
    echo "
    var point = [$suc10[2],$suc10[1]];
    var marker=L.marker(point, {icon: $cm3}).bindPopup('<p>$suc10[0] <br> m2: $suc10[3] Sus <br> Sup: $suc10[4] .m2 </p>'"?>+' <a id="<?php echo $suc10[5]?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info view_data">Detalles</a>'<?php echo").addTo(suc10);

    suc10.addLayer( marker );
    
    ";
}
echo "//----------  comparables cbba ultimos 10 registros  potosi --------------------------------------------
var pt10 = new L.markerClusterGroup({disableClusteringAtZoom: 17});
";
while ($pt10 = pg_fetch_row($c_pt10)) {
    if($pt10[6]==0 and $pt10[7]>=1){$cm3='m3';}
            else {if($pt10[6]==0 and $pt10[7]==0){$cm3='pin';}else{
                $cm3='mc3';
            }

    }
    echo "
    var point = [$pt10[2],$pt10[1]];
    var marker=L.marker(point, {icon: $cm3}).bindPopup('<p>$pt10[0] <br> m2: $pt10[3] Sus <br> Sup: $pt10[4] .m2 </p>'"?>+' <a id="<?php echo $pt10[5]?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info view_data">Detalles</a>'<?php echo").addTo(pt10);

    pt10.addLayer( marker );
    
    ";
}
```

Estos son las conexiones que tengo para con la base de datos ahí están definidos sus marcadores.

```
    echo " 
var overlays10num = {

    'Comparables SUC Ultimos 10':suc10,
    'Comparables PT Ultimos 10':pt10,
    
};
L.control.layers('',overlays10num, {position: 'topright'}).addTo(map);
";
```

aca estan los marcadores para q aparescan en el mapa
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto la imagen en la parte izquierda se pueden ver los marcadores mi pregunta es que si existe alguna manera de concatenarlos para que aparezcan dos marker en uno solo ejemplo:

```
        echo " 
var overlays10num = {

    'Comparables SUC Ultimos 10':suc10 + pt10,
    'Comparables PT Ultimos 10':pt10,
    
};
L.control.layers('',overlays10num, {position: 'topright'}).addTo(map);
";
```

Intente hacerlo así pero ya no me aparecen los datos en el mapa.
Espero darme a entender si alguien alguna ves lo hizo o tiene alguna guía de como poder hacerlo le agradecería mucho igual sigo buscando maneras de hacerlo gracias.

Comment: Llegando año y medio tarde :) ¿Llegaste a encontrar respuesta a tu pregunta? Honestamente no se entiende muy bien qué querías hacer... ¿Querías agrupar _markers_?